# On GitHub actions, "pip install playsound" failed with the "OSError: could not get source code" error

Tags: python-3.x, pip, github-actions

I am running **Pylint** on the **GitHub** actions.
Before it runs, it installs the module **playsound** during the dependencies installation.

The checks all failed with **Python 3.8**, **3.9**, and **3.10**.

It seems to fail with the following error:

```
OSError: could not get source code
```

Do you have any idea to fix it?

```
Collecting playsound==1.3.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Downloading playsound-1.3.0.tar.gz (7.7 kB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'error'
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [23 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.11/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.11/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.11/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-uqafiw95/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 341, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-uqafiw95/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 323, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-uqafiw95/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 487, in run_setup
          super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-uqafiw95/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 338, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
        File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.11/x64/lib/python3.10/inspect.py", line 1139, in getsource
          lines, lnum = getsourcelines(object)
        File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.11/x64/lib/python3.10/inspect.py", line 1121, in getsourcelines
          lines, lnum = findsource(object)
        File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.11/x64/lib/python3.10/inspect.py", line 958, in findsource
Error:           raise OSError('could not get source code')
      OSError: could not get source code
      [end of output]
```

What I have tried so far is:

```py
>>> pip uninstall wheel
>>> pip install playsound
>>> pip install wheel
```

[This thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/termux/comments/116825n/oserror_could_not_get_source_code_pip_playsound/) kindly suggested this procedure, but did not work for me.

---

@Azeem,
Thanks for your suggestions!
Let me summarize the details of what I have tried so far.

- `requirements.txt`

```
playsound==1.3.0
```

- `.github/workflows/pylint.yml`

```yaml
name: Pylint

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        python-version: ["3.8", "3.9", "3.10"]
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Set up Python ${{ matrix.python-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-python@v3
      with:
        python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install -r requirements.txt
        pip install pylint
    - name: Analysing the code with pylint
      run: |
        pylint $(git ls-files '*.py')
```

The installation with this `requirements.txt` file works fine in the local environment with Python 3.10.9.

```bash
$ pip3 install -r requirements.txt
Collecting playsound==1.3.0
  Downloading playsound-1.3.0.tar.gz (7.7 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: playsound
  Building wheel for playsound (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for playsound: filename=playsound-1.3.0-py3-none-any.whl size=7022 sha256=6d5b836046d0875702d97edb41c78ad993e0057fc50dab24783790b6bf83b36d
  Stored in directory: /Users/username/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/24/f9/b3/2ed63b5d2a91bbf7da060acdc294c1335db338ec81f0c76e1b
Successfully built playsound
Installing collected packages: playsound
Successfully installed playsound-1.3.0
```

Comment: Does the same procedure work locally? If yes, include Python version and the relevant details in your question. Also, add your GHA workflow in your question.

Comment: @Azeem, Thanks for your suggestions! I have updated my post with the info you mentioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1464697/unable-to-install-playsound-using-pip), installing/upgrading `wheel` worked.

I tried the same with your use case and it worked fine.

Here's the sample workflow that I used:

```yaml
name: python_playsound_test

on: workflow_dispatch

jobs:
  ci:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        python-version: ["3.8", "3.9", "3.10"]

    steps:
    - name: Set up Python ${{ matrix.python-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-python@v3
      with:
        python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}

    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        mkdir test && cd test
        echo 'playsound==1.3.0' > requirements.txt

        python --version
        pip --version

        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install --upgrade wheel
        pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Here's the screenshot where it passed for the matrix:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you so much!! Adding the `pip install --upgrade wheel` before `pip install -r requirements.txt` did work!!!! Thanks a lot for your help!!!

Comment: @noriko: Glad to hear that. :) In addition, you might want to start using `venv` to contain your code. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html for more details.

Comment: I think I see your point! Currently, I am mixing all dependencies in my local, and that might have made it hard to find out the issue. I agree that it's good practice to keep dependencies separate by projects. Thanks a lot for your suggestions:)! I will learn more about `venv`!

Answer (score 3):

In my case upgrading only wheels didn't help, but `pip install --upgrade setuptools wheel` did :)